# How to copy text from PDF and paste into word without keeping the source format and linebreaks?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010

When I copy 2-3 paragraphs from a E-textbook PDF file and paste it to MS word,the new line(line breaks) in PDF also appears in MS word even though .It means a new line in PDF also becomes a new line the word.But this is causing inconvinience to me .Im preparing notes for my students and deleting the spaces and tabs to remove the empty spaces is too time-consuming.I want the content to come in a single line when I paste it or at least it should match the margins of the MS word.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

Copy text from your PDF into a text editor, for example [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Then, in Notepad++ you can do a search and replace to get rid of any formatting you dont need (i.e. linebreaks). Then copy your edited text from Notepad++ into Word and format to your liking.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1. It does not make the process simpler. You can even omit Notepad by pasting the text directly to a new and empty Word file (which you can open easily via CTRL+N) and do find-and-replace there.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste the text in the word. Select the option "Keep Text Only" . Please see the screenshot.

Hope if this helps.

Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca3Ka.png) creenshot.

Comment: This does ot remove unnecessary linebreaks introduced by the PDF format...